# Swift use custom type in array but always print type name not value

Tags: swift

I have a function to call API.
When I call designated key, it will give me list which I
take it to save into my array

```
var car = [Car]()
```

I use for-loop to get the key's value

```
for result in fromApiResult.designatedKey {
       self.car.append(Car(carName: result.Name, carType: result.Type))
    }
```

And I print out car, it looks like just Type

```
print("\(car)") // [Car,Car]
```

That's not what I want, I actually want it looked like below

Because I will use these data to show on TableView

```
var car = [Car(carName:"BMW",carType:"SUV")]
```

but If I use for-loop again on it, it can get correct value

```
 for result in car {
   print(result.carName) //"BMW"
 }
```

I'm really new, now good at questioning
if need more info just ask for me, Thanks.

Comment: Use `dump(car)` instead of `print("\(car)")`

Comment: 1) Appending to your array as a way of getting data "out" of an async api call isn't going to work, 2) your for loop could be better expressed as a simple call to map: `cars += fromApiResult.designatedKey { Car(carName: $0, carType: $1) }`, 3) You're seeing inconsistent printing behaviour because you're using `result.carName`, vs what the array description does, which is call `Car.description`, if it's available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below example which I found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/khramtsoff/ad84ba1b8a2e927c7b19aed5c36d5750)

First you need to create extension named `CustomStringConvertible`

```
extension CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var description: String = "\(type(of: self))("

        let selfMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        for child in selfMirror.children {
            if let propertyName = child.label {
                description += "\(propertyName): \(child.value), "
            }
        }

        description += "<\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self as AnyObject).toOpaque())>)"

        return description
    }
}
```

then your class needs to confirm that extension like:

```
class Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init (name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

And now you can print your objects in console like:

```
let alex = Person(name: "Alex", age: 20)
print(alex) // Person(name: Alex, age: 20, <0x000060c000058d20>)
```

For more info read [HERE](https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/use-auto-describing-objects-with-customstringconvertible-49528b55f446).

Comment: Using mirror for this is a cool idea (especially because you would only ever use this for logs/print statements that aren't user-facing, and aren't often enough to be a performance concern. I would omit the the pointer though, it's meaningless for structs and enums.